# Get memory buffer with c++

Tags: c++, memory, buffer

I have C++ application which press Print Screen button.

How i can get memory buffer in c++ i want to use it in `GetBitmap`

Is there any function GetMethod() or something like that?

Comment: What platform/OS are you using?

Comment: If I had to guess I'd bet the actual question is "My application programmatically activates the 'print screen' button in windows _some version_.  How do I now access the image that was captured by that print screen operation?"  Sadly, I have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WHAT?

if you want a chunk of memory to play with you can do the following

```
 #include <vector>
 #include <cstdint>

 std::vector<int8_t> buffer(num_of_bytes);
 buffer.data(); // this is the 'raw' buffer be careful with it
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're on Windows, and your application is triggering the built-in Print Screen functionality, same as if the user presses the actual Print Screen button on the keyboard, the image data is now on the clipboard. Use [GetClipboardData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649039%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and related functions to access it.